# Is this sentence correct? - usage of 'until'

Tags: adverbs

Talking about a person's skills at work.

> He likes solving problems that have *until now?/until then?* remained unresolved.

Meaning that nobody before him managed to solve them. He usually approaches problems that other people failed to solve before him.

Which time expression should go in that sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Your verb tense should match your adverb.

He likes solving problems that **had** until **then** remained unsolved.

He likes solving problems that **have** until **now** remained unsolved.

Which construction you choose depends on the context in which you are using it.

Comment: Thank you. Which context would be better if a person writes it about themselves in a covering letter to a potential employer?

Comment: I don't think I can answer that. It's a stylistic question of which fits with the rest of what you've written. Either option is grammatically correct.